# Vertically aligning an image to the bottom inside a bootstrap “column”?

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to vertically align an `img` to the ***bottom*** of a containing Bootstrap *column*.

How can this be accomplished?

---

## Example

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #00ff00">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
             <h1>green container</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #ff0000">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
            <h1>red container with lots of</h1>
             <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
             <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
             <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
             <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
             <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
             <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/00a/fff.png?text=I+want+to+touch+the+blue+container"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #0000ff">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
             <h1>blue container</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Abdull/KAccL/)

In above example, there are three containers. Each container has a distinctive color. I want the blueish image to touch the bottom blue container, not the top green container.

---

Bonus points if answer is able to abstract away from hard-programmed image sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the solution you are looking for...but the only way that I could think of to do it was to absolutely position the column within the row.  While this allows the column on the left to be a dynamic height, it loses the responsiveness...you'd probably have to define set widths for differing media.

A margin-top would allow the width to be responsive but would assume static height on the left, which is, I'm assuming, also not a good solution, since the fact that you put text in the left column implies you want a dynamic height.

**Dare I say TABLE???** I know, I know, "horrible idea", right?  But the `<td>`s stretch with the `<td>`s on the left in height, and the vertical-align:bottom; works within a TD.  Bad practice, or a practical solution, you decide.

```
<div class="row" style='position:relative;'>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
        <h1>red container with lots of</h1>
         <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
         <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
         <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
         <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
         <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
         <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style='position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;'>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/00a/fff.png?text=I+want+to+touch+the+blue+container"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We are so close to an accepted answer. :) [I made a JSFiddle with your current solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Abdull/R48na/). While the blueish image now fits snugly to the bottom blue container all the time, on narrower widths the image hides content from the red container (narrowing the vertical JSFiddle window frame provokes a smaller width): The line saying *last line* is hidden behind the image. Maybe there is a way on smaller screens (besides a hackish `.visible-xs`/`.hidden-xs`) to restore the usual Bootstrap behavior of aligning individual columns below each other?

Comment: @Abdull, the fact that it overlays the text is what I meant when I said you lose responsiveness. If you want it to stack on smaller screens, then making the above hidden-xs, and adding a new row with .visible-xs is your best bet. Otherwise, you'd need to use JavaScript, which would be even more of a hack.  There is no way to make an absolutely positioned element move out of the way for other elements.  Once an element is absolutely positioned, it is essentially in a world of its own.

Comment: Here is my solution which uses Bootstrap's `.visible-xs` and `.hidden-xs`. http://jsfiddle.net/Abdull/b8kHf/